# Is it Possible to Cache Method Invocations on Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, caching

Some methods on my web application are quite resource consuming and could be cached. They aren't dependent on global variables, temporal data or such, they are exclusively dependent on the parameters used on invocation.

Is there a simple way to cache those invocations? It would be cool to have them annotated with something like `@Cacheable`, giving some TTL and cache name.

Side note: those methods are implemented on services declared on `services.yml`.

Comment: are these stateless? Consider to use an http cache server such as Varnish

Comment: The final result (page) is always different, only a few methods on my service layer are possible to be cached.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a bundle that works exactly like you describe (the annotation is really called @Cacheable). I'm having difficulties getting it to work and posted an issue on their github.

But maybe you have more success (and if you do, please let me know).

See https://github.com/phpro/annotated-cache for how it should work.

And https://github.com/phpro/annotated-cache-bundle for its symfony bundle and its configs